# Getting file corrupt error while downloading the results in ms-excel from Hue editor

Tags: excel, hive, hue

I have below table and the records in the table is around  4449 .

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS archive.LIQ_Sublimit(
`EffDate` timestamp,
`SOD_PID_FACILITY` string,
`SOD_PID_SUBLIMIT` string,
`SOD_NME_SUBLIMIT` string,
`SOD_AMT_LIMIT` decimal(28,3),
`ZONE_ID` string,
`REGION` string,
`etl_createddate` string,
`etl_createdby` string)

PARTITIONED BY (`businessdate` date)

STORED AS orc

location '/edl/appl/1sr14/archive/LIQ_Sublimit'
```

I executed below query in hue editor and the export the results as excel.

```
select * from archive.LIQ_Sublimit;
```

While opening the excel file, I am getting following error.

[image]

Once I select "Yes" , I get below message
[image]

**Please find the xml as below.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error224280_02.xml</logFileName>

<summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\u789286\Downloads\query-hive-213009.xlsx'</summary>

<removedRecords><removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord></removedRecords>

</recoveryLog>
```

**Could you please help me resolve this issue.**

Is this excel formatting issue or data issue in the table?

***In addition***: While downloading in csv, the timestamp and decimal data format is not coming up correctly.

**Hive-version** :2.3.6-

**Hue version**: 4

Comment: Why not export to csv so that you can open both in excel and any text editor so that you can find any issues with the data?

Comment: While downloading in csv, the timestamp and decimal data format is not coming up correctly.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include that?